# TextView in listview dissapears after scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-xml, android-adapter

I have a listview that im populating with items, but every time I scroll my list my feat textview is dissapearing. Does anyone know why is that happening and how can i fix that?

Here is part of my code from the adapter:

```
TextView feat = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songs_item_feat);
            feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());

            if (data.get(position).getFeat().length() == 0) {
                feat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());
            }
```

and my item xml layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_item_sel"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/songs_item_number"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/song_item_thumb"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:padding="1dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songs_item_album_title"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:text="title"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songs_item_feat"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:text="feat"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/songs_item_album_singer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:maxWidth="150dp"
            android:text="singer"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="20"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/songs_item_play"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/play_pr"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/songs_item_video"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/video_pr"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/songs_item_download"
            android:layout_width="38dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/down_no"
            android:contentDescription="@string/app_name" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: whats condition for show and hide Textview ??

Comment: @andruboy   `if (data.get(position).getFeat().length() == 0) {
                feat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());
            }` Im using this for removing the height of the textview if it is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your code `feat.setVisibility(View.GONE);` written so  it is gone and you are not doing visible again :)

**Edit 1**

Do like this

```
TextView feat = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songs_item_feat);


        if (!TextUtil.isEmpty(data.get(position).getFeat()) {
            feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());
            feat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
             feat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
```

Comment: Yap that's what i did. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
            if (data.get(position).getFeat().length() == 0) {
            feat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

This hides the visibility, Im not sure what youre making from the little context you're giving us. but this seems nedlessly complicated. Why not just build an adapter and handle data more static?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hide your textview, then show some warning message when no data is there..like:

```
        TextView feat = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.songs_item_feat);
        feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());

        if (data.get(position).getFeat().length() == 0) {
            feat.setText("No Data");
        } else {
            feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());
        }
```

And also check your `data` size in `try{}catch{}` block.. i think it has not sufficient data in front of increasing position.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once, guess this should help:

```
if (data.get(position).getFeat().length() == 0) {
            feat.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        } else {
            feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());
            feat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add `feat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` in else condition, like -

```
else {
            feat.setText(data.get(position).getFeat());
            feat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
```